# DMV Query using sys.dm_exec_sql_text fails if any Databases in Single-User mode

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using the following Query to look @ Query Plans

However I have found when I have any Single-User only Database on the instance
I encounter the following error if it already has a user in it
Msg 924, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Database '' is already open and can only have one user at a time.

```
SELECT DB_NAME(st.dbid) AS database_name
,OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid) AS object_name
,cp.usecounts -- Use in place of qs.execution_count for whole plan count
,CAST(SUM(qs.total_worker_time)/(cp.usecounts*1.) as decimal(12,2)) AS avg_cpu_time
,CAST(SUM(qs.total_logical_reads + qs.total_logical_writes)/(cp.usecounts*1.) as decimal(12,2)) AS avg_io
,SUM(qs.total_elapsed_time)/(cp.usecounts)/1000 as avg_elapsed_time_ms
,st.text AS sql_text
,qs.plan_handle
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp ON qs.plan_handle = cp.plan_handle
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) st
WHERE NOT(DB_NAME(st.dbid) = 'SingleUserDBName')  -- Tried to filter it out but no joy
AND (DB_NAME(st.dbid) = 'MultiUserDBName')
GROUP BY st.dbid, st.objectid, cp.usecounts, st.text, qs.plan_handle
```

SQL Build 10.50.1746

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version that doesn't rely on deprecated compatibility views (sysprocesses won't exist forever). It is a little more convoluted than your original query but I have tested it and plans from single_user or restricted_user databases are not returned (they are if the database is returned to multi_user). You may also want to add other checks, e.g. whether the database is online.

```
WITH valid_plans AS
(
    SELECT plan_handle, usecounts, [dbid], [objectid], [sql_handle],
        cpu, [io], [time]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT cp.plan_handle, cp.usecounts, pa.attribute, pa.value,
            [cpu] = qs.total_worker_time, [time] = qs.total_elapsed_time,
            [io] = qs.total_logical_reads + qs.total_logical_writes,
            qs.[sql_handle]
        FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp
        ON qs.plan_handle = cp.plan_handle
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(cp.plan_handle) AS pa
    ) AS x
    PIVOT (MAX(x.value) FOR x.attribute IN ([dbid], [objectid])) AS o
),
query_stats AS 
(
    SELECT 
        [dbid], [objectid] = CONVERT(INT, [objectid]),
        [plan_handle], [sql_handle],
        usecounts, cpu, [io],[time]
    FROM valid_plans
    WHERE [sql_handle] IS NOT NULL 
    AND [dbid] NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT database_id
            FROM sys.databases
            WHERE user_access <> 0
    )
)
SELECT database_name = DB_NAME(st.[dbid]),
    [object_name] = OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.[dbid]),
    qs.usecounts,
    avg_cpu_time = CAST(SUM(qs.[time])/(qs.usecounts*1.0) AS DECIMAL(12,2)),
    avg_io = CAST(SUM(qs.[io])/(qs.usecounts*1.0) AS DECIMAL(12,2)),
    avg_elapsed_time = SUM(qs.[time])/(qs.usecounts)/1000,
    sql_text = st.[text],
    qs.plan_handle
FROM query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.[sql_handle]) AS st
GROUP BY
    st.[dbid], 
    st.objectid,
    qs.usecounts, 
    st.[text], 
    qs.plan_handle;
```

Comment: Aaron .. you have solved this problem.. I thank you kindly for your assistance, limiting the plan handles to only those dB's we can access was the key I see  .. I also hadn't used dm_exec_plan_attributes before and will have to look @ that some in due course

Comment: Also seems to work fine with Database instance having DBs offline.. I didn't get any errors with those before so internally there would be no plans for them; so no problems if they are offline